# Getting "PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to" ORACLE 11G

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I am getting this strange error message while executing some code in my ORACLE 11G database.

This is my code:

```
SET serveroutput ON;      
DECLARE

   l_xxe_customer_rec       CUSTOMER_REC;
   l_xxe_site_tab           SITE_TAB_TABLE; 
   l_xxe_site_rec           SITE_TAB;
   l_xxe_contact_tab        CONTACT_TAB_TABLE;
   l_xxe_contact_rec        CONTACT_TAB;
   l_xxe_relate_tab         RELATE_TAB_TABLE;
   l_xxe_relate_rec         RELATE_TAB;
   
   x_cust_account_id        NUMBER;
   x_party_id                   NUMBER;
   x_contact_party_id        NUMBER;
   x_return_status            VARCHAR2 ( 2000 ) ;
   x_msg_count               NUMBER;
   x_msg_data                VARCHAR2 ( 2000 ) ;
                            

BEGIN
    -- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- HEADER
    -- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   l_xxe_customer_rec := CUSTOMER_REC ('785710'
,'I'
,'RANDOM'
,'N'
);
    

    -- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Site 
    -- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    l_xxe_site_tab :=  SITE_TAB_TABLE();
   l_xxe_site_rec := SITE_TAB('0712892'                                     
                              ,'01-0712892-01'                             
                              ,'Y'                                         
                              );
              
       
    l_xxe_site_tab.extend;
    l_xxe_site_tab(l_xxe_site_tab.count):= l_xxe_site_rec;



    -- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Contact
    -- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   l_xxe_contact_tab :=  CONTACT_TAB_TABLE();
   l_xxe_contact_rec :=  CONTACT_TAB('0712892'                                  
                                      ,''                                      
                                    );


    
    l_xxe_contact_tab.extend;
    l_xxe_contact_tab(l_xxe_contact_tab.count):= l_xxe_contact_rec;


   l_xxe_relate_tab :=  RELATE_TAB_TABLE();


    
   dbms_output.put_line ( 'CALLING API');
   INT_IN_PK.main (p_customer_rec      => l_xxe_customer_rec                                       
                                 ,p_site_rec              => l_xxe_site_tab                                
                                 ,p_contact_rec         => l_xxe_contact_tab                                
                                 ,p_relate_rec           => l_xxe_relate_tab                                   
                                 ,x_party_id              => x_party_id 
                                 ,x_cust_account_id   => x_cust_account_id
                                 ,x_return_status       => x_return_status        
                                 ,x_msg_count          => x_msg_count           
                                 ,x_msg_data            => x_msg_data
                                 );
   dbms_output.put_line ( 'x_return_status = '||SUBSTR ( x_return_status, 1, 255 ) ) ;
   dbms_output.put_line ( 'x_msg_count = '||TO_CHAR ( x_msg_count ) ) ;
   dbms_output.put_line ( 'x_party_id = '||TO_CHAR ( x_party_id ) ) ;
   dbms_output.put_line ( 'x_cust_account_id = '||TO_CHAR ( x_cust_account_id ) ) ;
   dbms_output.put_line ( 'x_contact_party_id = '||TO_CHAR ( x_contact_party_id ) ) ;
   dbms_output.put_line ( 'x_msg_data = '|| SUBSTR ( x_msg_data, 1, 255 ) ) ;
   IF x_return_status != 'S' THEN
      FOR I      IN 1..x_msg_count
      LOOP
         dbms_output.put_line ( I||'.'||SUBSTR ( FND_MSG_PUB.Get ( p_encoded=> FND_API.G_FALSE ), 1, 255 ) ) ;
      END LOOP;
   END IF;

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ( 'Error: '||SQLERRM ) ;
END;
```

Error messages:

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to
> 'CUSTOMER_REC'
>
> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CONTACT_TAB'

How may i solve this? Am i doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is happening because your the types `CUSTOMER_REC` and `CONTACT_TAB` get a wrong number or types or arguments when they're initialized. That is not the complete error message, there should be line numbers indicating the exact line the error is thrown.
Solution: check the definition of those type and verify the arguments and position. The code you posted uses "positional notation": it relies on the argument position so it assumes that the first parameter is always the same. It is safer to use "named notation". If then order of the arguments in the underlying type changes, the code will not fail. Here is an example to illustrate the error you are seeing:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE cust_rec IS RECORD (
    customer_name VARCHAR2(100),
    salary        NUMBER
  );
  l_cust cust_rec;
BEGIN
  -- assign value using positional notation. This works but relies on "customer_name" being first argument.
  l_cust := cust_rec('Koen',100); 
  -- assign value using named notation. This is advised. Code is more solid
  l_cust := cust_rec(customer_name => 'Koen',salary =>100);
  -- assign wrong type of value to "salary". Fails with PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments ...
  l_cust := cust_rec('Koen',SYSDATE);
  -- use named notation for a non-existing argument. Fails with PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments ...
  l_cust := cust_rec(last_name => 'Koen');
END;
/

Error report -
ORA-06550: line 13, column 13:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CUST_REC'
ORA-06550: line 13, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 15, column 13:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CUST_REC'
ORA-06550: line 15, column 3:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Note that the error message gives the exact position.

So to come back to your code:

```
    l_xxe_site_tab :=  SITE_TAB_TABLE();
-- line below is failing
   l_xxe_site_rec := SITE_TAB('0712892'                                     
                              ,'01-0712892-01'                             
                              ,'Y'                                         
                              );
              
       
    l_xxe_site_tab.extend;
    l_xxe_site_tab(l_xxe_site_tab.count):= l_xxe_site_rec;



    -- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- Contact
    -- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   l_xxe_contact_tab :=  CONTACT_TAB_TABLE();
-- line below is failing
   l_xxe_contact_rec :=  CONTACT_TAB('0712892'                                  
                                      ,''                                      
                                    );
```

Why are they failing ? Because the declaration of the 2 types doesn't match how they're assigned as illustrated above. Since you have not provided the type specification it is not possible to tell you exactly why but the example above should point you in the correct direction.

Comment: Thanks pal, the type specification was wrong :)

Comment: Glad to hear it help